# How can I post documents using Sanity?

Tags: api, sanity

I'm using sanity cms for an application, and I have some documents stored on db. Which query should I use the create another document in the database from my frontend?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create a client file (for example, in scr folder in React) and add where appropriate 
//In my case, I have a token and project Id in a.env file

import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBulder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = sanityClient({
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
    dataset:'production',
    apiVersion: '2020-10-21',
    useCdn:true,
    token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_API_TOKEN,
});

const builder = imageUrlBulder(client);
export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);


//in the other file include these lines

import { client } from '../client';

//these fields should match your schema declaration
const doc = {
  _id: "yout_id",
  _type: 'your_doc_type',
  userName:name,
  image: imageUrl,
}

client.createIfNotExists(doc)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("document created")
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

[check this video for more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxXyfkrP298&t=3590s)